# Error when search values in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, linked-list

I have a linked list with the following values:

```
switch_list = [[4, 1, 2, 2],
               [4, 2, 3, 2],
               [3, 1, 1, 3],
               [3, 2, 4, 2],
               [1, 3, 3, 1],
               [1, 2, 2, 1], 
               [2, 1, 1, 2],
               [2, 2, 4, 1]]
```

My goal is to compare an integer with the first value of the all linked-list and then, return a new list with filtered values.

Example: I want all values in switch_list with the first number equals 4, then the function will returns:

```
[[4, 1, 2, 2], [4, 2, 3, 2],]
```

Here is my program:

```
def bucket(value, input): 

    output = []

    for i in input:
        if i[0][0] == value:
            output.append(i)

    return output
```

And here is the output error:

```
File "matrix_optimizate.py", line 63, in bucket
  if i[0][0] == value:
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already iterating over the outer list, so there's no need for two index lookups.

```
for i in input:
    if i[0] == value:
        output.append(i)
```

Also, there's a much more elegant way to do this using `filter`:

```
def bucket(input, value):
    return filter(lambda x: x[0] == value, input)
```

At which point you probably don't even need to have it as it's own function.

And lastly you could use a list comprehension as well:

```
[i for i in input if i[0] == value]
```

Comment: Great! Just another issue about your comment: If I consider performance, is there some difference in use one of those cases?

Comment: Technically `filter` and list comprehensions are optimized for what they do, but 99/100 times the performance difference is nil.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that `input` is going to be your list of lists.  In that case,

```
for i in input:
```

will give you each sub list as `i` during each iteration.  By trying to access

```
i[0][0]
```

you are trying to access the first element of the element of the sublist.  In your example

- `i` would give `[4, 1, 2, 2]`
- `i[0]` would give `4`, and
- `i[0][0]` would therefore not make sense

Please try `i[0]` instead.

Edit: Please note that this answer only serves to point out your current problem.  [dursk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33325139/2512688) provides other solutions to what you are trying to perform as a whole and those options are much more powerful (list comprehension is a fantastic tool, I would recommend looking into it).

Comment: Nice break down of the problem!